# Is there any Geyser plugin providers

Tags: geyser

Is there any rpc providers that provides geyser plugin. Or should I develop the plugin myself. I only need typical account data update monitoring nothing customized.

Answer (score 4):

There are several RPC providers that use geyser plugins as part of their infrastructure. Then offer version services and data processing on the Solana blockchain data they ingest.

I would look at the following RPC providers to see if their services meet your needs:

- [Helius](https://helius.xyz)
- [Triton](https://Triton.one)
- [Blockdaemon](https://www.blockdaemon.com/get-started/nodes)
- [Hellomoon](https://hellomoon.io)

If you wanted to run your own custom geyser plugin, you would have to setup and maintain your own RPC node (and cover the cost of running that server)

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto what Nick has said, Helius is a great option, here are some more resources you can use to learn more about Geysers and make an informed decision.

https://docs.helius.xyz/high-performance-infra/dedicated-infrastructure/geyser-as-a-service

Feel free as well to visit our Discord, https://discord.gg/Helius to ask any other questions.

Disclaimer: This user employed by Helius.

Comment: Make sure you disclose your affiliation to Helius in the answer as according to the rules https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior Answer is good, just needs disclosure!

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, done sorry!